# How to get the IP address after 2 consecutive 403

Tags: python, regex

I am making a python log parser script where I need to print Ip the after 2 consecutive 403

```
12.115.14.240 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:40:03 -0400] "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 403 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"

202.167.250.99 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:41:10 -0400] "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?1424751982?1424776117 HTTP/1.1" 403 115656 "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php?tid=2186780&fpage=3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

120.115.144.240 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:40:03 -0400] "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"
```

My code is below

```
with open(log) as f:
    log = f.read()
    ###if condition to show to get 2 consecutive 403
          iplist = re.findall(rx,log)
```

My output is

```
120.115.144.240
```

Comment: What if there's 3 consecutive 403? Do you want to get first non-403 IP address after at least two 403s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression on s `mode` might return those IPs:

```
403.*?403.*?\s{2,}(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

or with more boundaries:

```
"\s+\b403\b.*?"\s+\b403\b.*?\s{2,}(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SLcBlc/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"403.*?403.*?\s{2,}(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"

test_str = """

12.115.14.240 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:40:03 -0400] "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 403 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"

202.167.250.99 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:41:10 -0400] "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?1424751982?1424776117 HTTP/1.1" 403 115656 "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php?tid=2186780&fpage=3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

120.115.144.240 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:40:03 -0400] "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"

12.115.14.240 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:40:03 -0400] "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 403 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"

202.167.250.99 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:41:10 -0400] "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?1424751982?1424776117 HTTP/1.1" 403 115656 "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php?tid=2186780&fpage=3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

120.115.144.240 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:40:03 -0400] "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"


"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
['120.115.144.240', '120.115.144.240']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/p8yyKR/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/p8yyKR/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There You go:

```
result = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', log)[-2]
```

Output:

```
120.115.144.240
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the 403 appears consistently as the 9th field separated by spaces and the ip numbers is always at the beginning of the line.

Another option is to take advantage of those patterns and use quantifiers to get to the right part and prevent unnecessary backtracking.

Assuming a single space between the parts of the line, you could match till the first 403. Then match all the lines that do not have 403 until you find the next line.

After that second 403, capture the first ip number which is at the start of the next line.

```
^\S+(?: \S+){7} 403 .*(?:\r?\n(?!\S+(?: \S+){7} 403 ).*)*\r?\n\S+(?: \S+){7} 403 .*(?:\r?\n|\r)+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the line
- `\S+(?: \S+){7} 403 .*` Match 403 at the 9th field and match rest of line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!\S+(?: \S+){7} 403 ).*` Match whole line where 403 is not at the 9th field
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n\S+(?: \S+){7} 403 .*` Match 1+ newlines and match 403 at the 9th field and match rest of line
- `(?:\r?\n)+` Match 1+ times a newline
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` Capture in group 1 and ip like pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W6VAtZ/1)

Taking spaces or tabs into account, you might use [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Sgsu18/1)